# How many different protein coding genes are in the Human Biome?

Tags: human-biology, microbiology, genomics

There are approximately 20k protein-coding genes found in the human genome. This number is presumably very small when considering all the genomes found in the diverse microbes associated with the human body.

Is there an estimate for the total number of protein-coding genes found in human microbiome?

Comment: What is the relation between microbiome and human genome?

Comment: Sorry, I mean only the human microbiome.

Comment: Still?? Microbiome is the micor-organisms in human body. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microbiome

Comment: Yes, I'm asking how many different genes are associated with a human and its resident symbionts, i.e. the number of protein-coding genes in the human genome + the number of protein-coding genes in the human microbiota.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Human Microbiome Project collected samples as shown in the image below from healthy volunteers:

[image]

They give an estimate of about 8 Million genes in the human microbiome, which is about 360x the number of genes in the human genome. See [here](http://www.nih.gov/news/health/jun2012/nhgri-13.htm) for their press release with a lot of information. Additionally these two articles are as well interesting, if you want to dive deeper into the stuff:

- [A framework for human microbiome research](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v486/n7402/full/nature11209.html)
- [Structure, function and diversity of the healthy human microbiome](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v486/n7402/full/nature11234.html)

Answer (score 3):

### Human Microbiome Project

According to Published data on HMP website:

- The human microbiome consists of all the microorganisms that reside in or on the human body.
- They may cause illness but some are necessary for good health.
- There total count is 10 times more than Human cells.
- ~800 genomes had been sequenced.
- ~5000 Human sample had been used.
- Include 14 disease project samples.
- Total data stored on the DACC resource is 14 terabytes.
- Total protein(~8 million) coding genes found to be 360x of number of human genes

Source:

[1] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_Microbiome_Project

[2] http://commonfund.nih.gov/hmp/index

Comment: These look like numbers for the human genome only.

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd estimate there are at least hundreds of thousands of different protein-coding genes associated with a human.

Comment: I know. Can you edit the question, it is actually confusing? You need to know the number of genes in human Microbiome which have an effect in human genome?

Comment: Thanks @Devashish I tried to clarify the question. I hope it makes more sense. And no, the genes do not have to be known to affect the human genome; they just need to be resident.

Comment: "360x more abundant than human genes" looks like a good answer. So, probably millions of genes.

Comment: Would you consider exactly same genes from different microbes as different genes? By gene do you mean the genes in the genome or gene products?

Comment: The main text of your answer is entirely copied from [a Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_Microbiome_Project#Milestones). While you mentioned the source at the end of your post, you didn't mark the text as a quote. This is still plagiarism and not allowed on this site. You have to make clear any place where you quote a source verbatim. Answers should also not be taken entirely from external sources, they should be in your own words and quotes should be only for support.

Comment: @WYSIWYG I think I would consider the same gene found in two different microbe species to be different as they operate within a different genomic environment. But I'm not sure. I imagine that there is a lot of mutualistic sharing of gene products between microbes, and probably some horizontal gene transfer as well. The answer I'm most looking for is some quantification of genetic and molecular information.